# How to execute procedure after time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Orders` in Mysql, that contains orders.

Each order has some reviews in another table `OrdersReviews`.

How to execute procedure after specific time after creating order?

**My logic is:**

After adding order to table, fix added time and order id. Then tell procedure to launch after as sample: `current time >`order added time + 30`

Does Mysql support something like thatç like cron manager?

Comment: Run a scheduler every 30 mins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WAITFOR COMMAND**
I think this is what you are looking for. The comand blocks the execution of the procedure for the time you want and then continues.

It is very useful because you shall combine it with triggers, other stored procedures and even set functions.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), good luck.

Comment: Okay, can MySQL run procedure time after time? Like a cron manager?

Comment: İ just need to run stored procedure each 5 minutes

Comment: In MYSQL phpadmin I have events is it?

Comment: Yeah sure, you have to make a procedure that runs WAITFOR (with DELAY COMMAND set to ‘00:05’) inside a WHILE so it gets constantly executed. Be careful because it is a processor consuming operation, like any chronometered operation.

Comment: What does it mean: Execute every (MINUTE_SECOND) how to set 5 minutes?

Comment: In a sample on the link I handled, to create a 2hour delay, they use WAITFOR DELAY ‘02:00’; so for 5 minutes you should use WAITFOR DELAY ‘00:05’;

Comment: Is it correct? `DROP EVENT `Choose Order Perfomer`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Choose Order Performer` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE_SECOND STARTS '2018-12-01 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES (1)`?

Comment: I’m not sure how that query works, I never tried it on this scenario. But I think it should be EVERY 5 MINUTE_SECOND, right?